Raspberry Pi 3 crashes when installing h5py
I'm trying to install tensorflow on my Raspberry Pi 3. I have the newest image of the Raspberry Pi OS 64bit (bookworm).
Python version is 3.11.
The installation freezes at
Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml) ...

After a few minutes the OS crashes.
Using pip install h5py also results in a crash.
This happens with and without using the virtual environment (venv).
I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-9b05mXyyg
I also tried the suggested fix (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfcktE5BeGM).
Following commands from various previous answers also didn't help:
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
sudo apt install python3-dev 
sudo apt install python3-hdf5
sudo apt install libhdf5-serial-dev
pip install setuptools
pip install versioned-hdf5


Using pip install h5py==3.9.0 and following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLZWQlg-Pk0 solved it
